# Serverless Framework and DynamoDB: Unexpected token in JSON at JSON.parse

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Hi I followed this [Serverless + AWS REST API tutorial](https://serverless.com/blog/node-rest-api-with-serverless-lambda-and-dynamodb/) and it went great, I got it to work.

Now, I'm trying to modify it but have hit a wall while trying to submit data into the DynamoDB table.

Using Postman to submit a valid JSON object I get a 502 response. If I test the function in Lambda, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
  "trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at Runtime.module.exports.submit [as handler] (/var/task/api/interview.js:11:28)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)",
    "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
  ]
}
```

After searching for solutions, what I found out is that it seem like the `event` that is being passed as `JSON.parse(event)`is undefined.

Here's the serverless.yml:

```
service: interview

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    INTERVIEW_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    INTERVIEW_EMAIL_TABLE: "interview-email-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
      Resource: "*"

resources:
  Resources:
    CandidatesDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: "id"
            AttributeType: "S"   
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: "id"
            KeyType: "HASH"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.INTERVIEW_TABLE}

functions:
  interviewSubmission:
    handler: api/interview.submit
    memorySize: 128
    description: Submit interview information and starts interview process.
    events:
      - http: 
          path: interviews
          method: post
```

and the interview.js

```
'use strict';

const uuid = require('uuid');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.submit = (event, context, callback) => {
  const requestBody = JSON.parse(event);
  const fullname = requestBody.fullname;
  const email = requestBody.email;
  const test = requestBody.test;
  const experience = requestBody.experience;

  if (typeof fullname !== 'string' || typeof email !== 'string' || typeof experience !== 'number') {
    console.error('Validation Failed');
    callback(new Error('Couldn\'t submit interview because of validation errors.'));
    return;
  }

  submitInterviewP(interviewInfo(fullname, email, experience, test))
    .then(res => {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Sucessfully submitted interview with email ${email}`,
          interviewId: res.id
        })
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Unable to submit interview with email ${email}`
        })
      })
    });
};


const submitInterviewP = interview => {
  console.log('Submitting interview');
  const interviewInfo = {
    TableName: process.env.INTERVIEW_TABLE,
    Item: interview,
  };
  return dynamoDb.put(interviewInfo).promise()
    .then(res => interview);
};

const interviewInfo = (fullname, email, experience,test) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  return {
    id: uuid.v1(),
    fullname: fullname,
    email: email,
    experience: experience,
    test: test,
    submittedAt: timestamp,
    updatedAt: timestamp,
  };
};
```

If I replace the `event` param for a valid JSON object and then deploy again. I'm able to successfully insert the object into dynamoDB.

Any clues? Please let me know if there's anything I missing that could help.

Thanks!

Comment: On line 11 of your yml put single back ticks instead of double quotes.

Comment: As in `INTERVIEW_EMAIL_TABLE: 'interview-email-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}'`? Did that nothing! Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API Gateway stringify the request body in event's body property.

Currently you are trying to parse event object `const requestBody = JSON.parse(event);` which is wrong. You need to parse event.body property:

`const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);`

Comment: That didn't work either. The error changed slightly ` "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"` it used to say '...token o...', it now says '...token u...'

Comment: what does your request object look like? can you show us the payload?

Comment: Ok so, for some reason the POST works when I do it from Postman but the Lambda test fails with the same error... 
I successfully posted into dynamodb this object `{"fullname":"Fran","email": "ffff@gmail.com", "experience":1.5, "test": 123}`. I can GET all object too from the browser, postman or lambda. In postman I'm sending the standard params:  `Content-Type`:`application/json`. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: If you test it from Lambda console then event is just what you put in the "test configure". If you post data to API gateway endpoint point then your data will be stringified in `event.body`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense... is there any way I can test it directly on Lambda console? Is it just syntax aka enclosing the json in brackets or something?

Comment: change line 11 to `const requestBody = event.body ? JSON.parse(event.body) : event;`